# Bind grid with an ImageField

Tags: c#, gridview, data-binding

I have a requirement to bind a grid.  The data table structure like below

[image]

I need to bind the grid with username, nooflikes, badges. One more thing is the badges is a imagefield and need to seperate the badges with '|' symbol.

here in the first row need to seperate badges as www.img1 and www.img2 and bind as image.

I have added like this

```
List<UserInteractionList> TestList = new List<UserInteractionList>();
        UserInteractionList test;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            test = new UserInteractionList();
            test.UserName = reader["UserName"].ToString();
             test.Action = reader["nooflikes"].ToString();
            test.Image = reader["Badges"].ToString();
            TestList.Add(test);
        }  
dgv1.datasource = testlist;
dgv1.databind();




protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        string images= e.Row.Cells[2].Text;
        string[] strArray = x.Split('|');

        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
        {

            Image photoImageField = new Image();
            photoImageField.ImageUrl = strArray[i];
            e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(photoImageField);
        }

    }
```

I have added like this and in debugging I found that `GridView1_RowDataBound` each time I get null by evaluating `string images= e.Row.Cells[2].Text;`

Please help me to add this.

Thanks!

Comment: As you having n numbers of image , so you have to add a literal control under your gridview Item Template, then on code-behind @ `GridviewRowBond` fetch the badges, split it, add dynamic image control with src and bind whole to literal control

Comment: Thanks for the respose.. Can you just give an example.. That will help me more

Comment: Post your code, Gridview HTML MARKUP n all

Comment: add it in your post, so other can also understand and reply you

Comment: Modified the question.. Can u pls have a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here first am saving the image /bagde into a hidden field, then on GridviewRowcommand we fetch the value from hidden field,  split it add dynamic image control to Panel Control

pseudo code :

HTML Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Col1">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Value='<%# Bind("Image") %>' runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Col2">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserName ") %>' ></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col3">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Panel ID="myPanelContainer" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
                           
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

---

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HiddenField hd1 = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("HiddenField1");
            Panel pnl = (Panel)e.Row.FindControl("myPanelContainer");

            string[] strArray = hd1.Value.Split('|');

            for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
            {
                Image photoImageField = new Image();
                photoImageField.ImageUrl = strArray[i];

                pnl.Controls.Add(photoImageField);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `RowDataBound` event, the row's [`DataItem` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem(v=vs.110).aspx) will be set to the item from the data source to which the row is being bound.

In this case, that will be an instance of your `UserInteractionList` class.

All you need to do is cast the `DataItem` to the `UserInteractionList` class, and access the relevant property:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var dataItem = (UserInteractionList)e.Row.DataItem;
    string images = dataItem.Image;
    string[] strArray = images.Split('|');

    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Image photoImageField = new Image();
        photoImageField.ImageUrl = strArray[i];
        e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(photoImageField);
    }
}
```

You can simplify this by using a `TemplateField` with a nested list:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Images">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ListView runat="server"
        DataSource='<%# Eval("Image", "{0}").Split(new[] { "|" }) %>'
    >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image runat="server"
            ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>'
        />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If you can modify the `UserInteractionList` class, you can simplify this further by adding a new property for the split images:

```
public class UserInteractionList
{
    ...

    public string[] Images
    {
         get { return Image.Split('|'); }
    }
}
```

You would then use that property as the data source of the nested list:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Images") %>'>
```